# how to use JBoss BPM Suite to develop and create web projects?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-developer-studio, jboss-web

can we use JBoss BPM Suite to develop and create web projects?
if the answer is yes, where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not possible to create web project in BPM Suite. For web project you have to use IDE. In BPM Suite you can create only project(jar) which contains assets like BPMN porocess, rule file, and data objects,..etc

Comment: you mean by IDE jboss-developer-studio?

Comment: if i need to develop web project using business process, then i must use IDE ( jboss-developer-studio)?

Comment: Yes IDE means Eclipse or JBoss developer studio. There are two approaches to use bpmn process in web application. 1. Create BPMN process in web designer, build project and place kjar into web application classpath. 2. Create BPMN files through BPMN2 plugin available in IDE and place them in web application classpath.

Comment: last question: can i generate web pages from BPMN process?

Comment: no, web pages are different and BPMN process is different.

Comment: then what is the benefit to place kjar into web application?

Comment: All the BPMN/rule files will be at one place and it will be easy for you to replace with new versions.